# What are the "standard Gtk+ toolkit command line options"?

Tags: command-line, gtk, synaptic

I have a problem with the 'synaptic' application (GUI version of apt), and was hoping to get some debug output from it. The man page however has just a couple of command line options and this very helpful statement:

"Synaptic accepts all of the standard Gtk+ toolkit command line options as well as the following:"

Unfortunately, there's no indication of how I might determine what those are, and my googlefu has so far been unhelpful..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From another GTK+ application (gnome-terminal) which supports --help-gtk at the command line:

```
GTK+ Options
  --class=CLASS            Program class as used by the window manager
  --name=NAME              Program name as used by the window manager
  --display=DISPLAY        X display to use
  --gtk-module=MODULES     Load additional GTK+ modules
  --g-fatal-warnings       Make all warnings fatal
```

Edit: "chromium-browser -h " gives these [this link](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/gtk-running.html) and [this link](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/gtk-x11.html) from library.gnome.org with a useful syopsis (especially the first link).